# my apps dont run after update eclipse & adt

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I updated Sdk manager & eclipse & Adt
but now new android app dont run.
my android app automatically create actionbaractivity & import android-support-v7

this is my error log:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MainActivity.java   /testpro/src/com/example/testpro    line 9  Java Problem
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MainActivity.java   /testpro/src/com/example/testpro    line 13 Java Problem
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MainActivity.java   /testpro/src/com/example/testpro    line 34 Java Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.   styles.xml  /testpro/res/values-v14 line 8  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml  /testpro/res/values line 7  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml  /testpro/res/values-v11 line 7  Android AAPT Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /testpro/src/com/example/testpro    line 14 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /testpro/src/com/example/testpro    line 21 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /testpro/src/com/example/testpro    line 31 Java Problem
The import android.support cannot be resolved   MainActivity.java   /testpro/src/com/example/testpro    line 3  Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MainActivity MainActivity.java   /testpro/src/com/example/testpro    line 21 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method  MainActivity.java   /testpro/src/com/example/testpro    line 12 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method MainActivity.java   /testpro/src/com/example/testpro    line 19 Java Problem
The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method   MainActivity.java   /testpro/src/com/example/testpro    line 26 Java Problem

Comment: try to clear (clean) your project

Comment: I cleared but I have my problem yet

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the project you are working on from Package Explorer
2. Go to "Properties"
   3 Go to "Java Build Path" from the right tree structure
3. Go to the "Libraries" tab
4. Choose the "Add Library" button
5. Select "JRE System Library"
6. Hit "Next"
7. The radio button will prompt the Workspace default JRE, and let it be that way
8. Hit "Finish"